# Changing a block in Trackmania Nations Forever's track editor

Tags: trackmania-forever

Is there any way to change a block in Trackmania Nations Forever's track editor without having to removing it and creating a new one? I basically just want to change the block type, not its location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nope you can't change a block without deleting